# Data design best practices for customer data

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I am trying to store customer attributes in a MySQL database although it could be any type of database. I have a customer table and then I have a number of attribute tables (status, product, address, etc.)

The business requirements are to be able to A) look back at a point in time to see if a customer was active or what address they had on any given date and B) have a customer service rep be able to put things like entering future vacation holds. I customer might call today and tell the rep they will be on vacation next week.

I currently have different tables for each customer attribute. For instance, the customer status table has records like this:

| CustomerID | Status | dEffectiveStart | dEffectiveEnd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Active | 2022-01-01 | 2022-05-01 |
| 1 | Vacation | 2022-05-02 | 2022-05-04 |
| 1 | Active | 2022-05-05 | 2099-01-01 |

When I join these tables the sql typically looks like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM customers c
JOIN customerStatus cs 
  on cs.CustomerID = c.CustomerID 
  and curdate() between cs.dEffectiveStart and cs.dEffectiveEnd
```

While this setup does work as designed, it is slow. The query joins themselves aren't too bad, but when I try to throw an Order By on its done. The typical client query would pull 5-20k records. There are 5-6 other similar tables to the one above I join to a customer.

Do you any suggestions of a better approach?

Comment: Using EXPLAIN in front of your query can give you details and optimization paths, making sure you're utilizing indexes.

Comment: So you think the way I've designed the data is fine, but to look into the optimization piece more?

Comment: This is usually the case in mysql . Do you have indexes in the tables? . [about index](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_create_index.asp) .

Comment: Another good way is to create a new table and redirect the related table in that table using the trigger (delete, edit, insert .. etc)

Comment: How would the triggers work on future dates?

Answer (score 0):

That `ON` clause is very hard to optimize.  So, let me try to 'avoid' it.

If you are always (or usually) testing `CURDATE()`, then I recommend this schema design pattern.  I call it History + Current.

- The History table contains many rows per customer.
- The Current table contains only "current" info about each customer -- one row per customer.  Your `SELECT` would need only this table.

Your design is "proper" because the current status is not redundantly stored in two places.  My design requires changing the `status` in both tables when it changes.  This is a small extra cost when changing the "status", for a big gain in `SELECT`.

**More**

The Optimizer will probably transform that query into

```
SELECT * 
FROM customerStatus cs 
JOIN customers c
  ON cs.CustomerID = c.CustomerID 
WHERE curdate() >= cs.dEffectiveStart
  AND curdate() <= cs.dEffectiveEnd
```

(Use `EXPLAIN SELECT ...; SHOW WARNINGS;` to find out exactly.)

In a plain `JOIN`, the Optimizer likes to start with the table that is most filtered.  I moved the "filtering" to the `WHERE` clause so we could see it; I left the "relation" in the `ON`.

`curdate() >= cs.dEffectiveStart` *might* use an index on `dEffectiveStart`.  Or it _might` use an index to help the other part.

The Optimizer would probably notice that "too much" of the table would need to be scanned with either index, and eschew both indexes and simply do a table scan.

Then it will quickly and efficiently `JOIN` to the other table.